# Запуск JavaFX на любой машине

Tags: javafx

Пишу, значится, я свой проект в IDEA-е, пишу, и вдруг в голову пришла мысль запустить приложение на другом компе. И, товарищи, вы не поверите, я не знаю до сих пор (прошло n-часов поисков) как запустить... Я создал jar-ник, я создал html вместе с jnlp, запуская который я получаю error "The field <jnlp> href has an invalid value: JavaFXDemo" и эксепшн в этом же духе... Запуска HTML, мое приложение грузится, но опять вылетает сообщение, что невозможно запустить из-за настроек в безопасности браузера (Chrome).
Что я хочу - создать executable jar-ник или , по возможности, exe-файл. Как это сделать и где почитать об этом (желательно ссыль) ???

Comment: Читать здесь - http://skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html
Внимательно и далее по ссылкам. Вся ваша проблема в том, что вы пишете в крутом редакторе, который скрывает от вас понимание базовых принципов с самого начала.

Comment: не поверите, Евгений,я на Вашем сайте очень много чего нашел еще недели 2 назад и почерпнул. Даже стал вручную java->class->jar. И с манифестом разобрался и про философию почитал. Но хочется чтобы IDE все это делала, чтобы не тратить время на все эти манипуляции с CMD и прочим...) Ваш сайт очень полезен,спасибо! Но вопрос не закрыт)

Comment: Я вообще-то не Евгений (т.е. не автор сайта). Но хорошо, что почитали и согласны с выводами о том, что надо все-таки знать, как устроено, чтобы потом работать в IDE со спокойной совестью :)

Comment: прошу прощения, ошибся) но хочу таки задать вопрос: "можно создать десктопное JavaFX приложение?"

Comment: Да, конечно можно. Оберните все ресурсы, которые использует ваше приложение и раздавайте дистрибутивом. Ну это так, слишком пространный ответ, ибо созданное на одном компе можно переносить на другой, если перенести все то, что использует оригинал, само же собой.

Comment: Не буду утверждать (путь меня поправят, если я неправ), но относительно недавно JavaFX стал частью runtime и не требует отдельной инсталляции. Т.е. "беспроблемный" запуск обусловлен еще и версией пакета Java, установленного на той или иной машине.

Comment: спасибо! щас посмотрю что и как)

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже задавался подобным вопросом. [Посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523541/java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-windows). Просто так запустить jar - файл без jre у вас не получится. Обычно, как я понимаю, создается exe и рядом с ним кладется папка с рабочей версией jre. Смысл в том, что при запуске, программа открывается с помощью этого jre без его установки.