# Java приложение под windows

Tags: java, swing, javafx, maven, exe

Допустим я написал GUI, используя swing или JavaFX. Далее собираю чем-нибудь типа Maven и получаю jar. А дальше что?

- Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог запустить мое приложение как
  exe файл, при этом не устанавливая jre?
- Такое вообще возможно?
- Я помню видел в какой-то программе было сделано так, что jre хранится
  в    папке с установленной программой и запускается в момент запуска
  exe -    файла. Такое тяжело делается?

Comment: Используйте инструмент _Launch4j_. Читаем [тыц](http://www.devbug.info/2011/04/exe-java.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует прогамма, называющаяся Launch 4J. С помощью неё можно создать EXE файл из JAR файла, даже задав ему собственную иконку.

**Примечание.** Если работать в среде программирования Eclipse, то необходимо компилировать проект не в `JAR file`, а `Runnable JAR file`.

Comment: Допустим я сделал EXE файл с помощью программы Launch 4J. Могу я после этого запустить его без jre ?

Comment: Должно быть да. Попробуй. В Javadoc об этом не сказано. Нужно только чтобы желательно версии Jav'ы совпадали.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, гуглим java to exe, делается не тяжело, exe-файл вызывает java.exe и "натравливает" его на jar-файл как в командной строке, но весит много, если jre таскать с собой, а главное, зачем вообще для Windows писать приложения на Java, она для этого очень плохо подходит.

Comment: Я же выше написал, что делаю GUI на Java. На изучение других языков может не хватить времени. Кстати, не согласен, что Java не подходит совсем для windows. Многие программы, которые я запуская на windows написаны на Java. Например, IntelliJ Idea, Keil uVision, CooCox и многие другие. Более того, два последних примера не портированы на Linux (что грустно, конечно).

Comment: @faoxis То есть вы вообще не видели других языков, но имеете мнение, что Java хорошо подходит для Windows? Ну-ну.